# get Java/JVM path of the program in Windows Server

Tags: java, windows, powershell, jvm, server

I have 4-5 Instances of JAVA/JVM Running in Windows Server 2008 R2 Server, When I Open up Task Scheduler, I can see java.exe running, I am "not" able to find out the java instance details like what is the program? is it Tomcat? is it some Command Line etc?

From Task Manager , I could not get it? is  there a way to find out from Command Line (or) Powershell?

Answer (score 2):

In task manager, click View>Select Columns... and opt the command line column.

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd and type following command, it will show all java processes:

```
jps -vlm
```

Answer (score 1):

since you asked the powershell solution, you may use `Get-Process java | select Processname, Path`

Cheers,
GJ

Answer (score -1):

It's `%SystemRoot%\System32`. The copy of java.exe is placed there during installation. You can also right click on the process and look up containing folder.

Comment: That's not even the default installation location.